# How to set interval of synchronization in Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, configuration, sync

I want to ask about how to set interval of synchronization in Ubuntu One?

Because I don't want to immediately synchronize my changes of file (because in 1 minute there can be more than 10 changes in a file). This behaviour makes conflict and sometime my file reverted back to previous changes. If there is a configuration for synchronize every hour or only synchronize for files that has changed for more than 10 minutes maybe it would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no such setting. The only way to not sync files to the server is to disconnect, which you can do by pressing `Disconnect` in the Ubuntu One control panel application.

Comment: well, i guess it can't helped other than disconnect Ubuntu One for a moment. Thanks for your reply